# I'm reading about Test engineering for an upcoming interview. Can anybody help me with one or two somewhat ambiguous terms that I've come across?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, terminology

For an upcoming interview, I've been asked to be prepared to write test programs, and to be able to classify my tests as: border cases, stress, security, or error checking.

I'm a little unclear on what is meant by these terms. If anybody could provide any insight that would be great. Googling isn't turning up much info so I'm assuming that these are not official terms.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common term for "border cases" is "boundary testing". This is a good intro to black box testing which will give you more vocab to Google from: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~cah/G53QAT/G53QAT09pdf6up.pdf

I'm not familiar with the term "error checking" -- I guess it refers to testing error handling, but I may be wrong. See http://testingcorner.blogspot.com/2009/01/what-is-error-handling-testing.html

For the rest, just add "testing" and Google:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_testing

Comment: You're awesome. I've actually been reading a bit over the past hour and stumbled upon the boundary testing/black box stuff, but these are great resources. Thanks!

Comment: Woops, thought I did that already.